# How to choose a row for specific column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, distinct

I have a table that contains multiple rows with duplicate `ID` values:

| ID | Course1 | Course2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A1 | A2 |
| S1 | A1 | B1 |
| S2 | D1 | B1 |
| S2 | C1 | B1 |

I need to select the first row for each unique `ID` value, resulting in a table that includes only the first occurrence of each `ID`.

The desired resulting table should look like this:

| ID | Course1 | Course2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | A1 | A2 |
| S2 | D1 | B1 |

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first row" in a database table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: It would help if you could provide additional context.  Are you trying to write a program?  If so, what language?  Are you using a tool?

Comment: Yes I'm writing a program with python

Comment: how do you determine which row is the "top row"?  You need to add an `order by` clause to specify which is the top row.  This is usually some sort of unique ID or date...though I don't see anything resembling that in your structure.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (in my opinion) to select the first row for each `ID` is to use a `GROUP BY` statement. This will group the rows by their `ID` and allow you to select the first row for each group. Here is an example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

###### Result:

[[image: Picture of the result]